# How to set up autoscaling docker container instances in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've been trying to read through the documentation and have been watching lots of videos, and it seems there are a million different ways of achieving this in AWS, and it's very complicated to find out what is the easiest and most cost effective way of doing it.

Some places say beanstalk but others say it's restrictive. Some say EC2s within an autoscaling group fronted with an elastic load balancer. But what about Fargate? ECS? EC2 instances? App Runners? There are so many similar sounding services I'm finding it impossible to actually see the way forward.

So in layman's terms, what is the recommended approach here minimising cost and maximising simplicity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is necessarily going to be subjective since, as you point out, there are many ways to do it. IMHO, the best balance of cost and simplicity is ECS Fargate Spot. With ECS Fargate, you won't have to maintain EC2 instances, and you'll have significant savings by using the Spot market. [This article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/deep-dive-into-fargate-spot-to-run-your-ecs-tasks-for-up-to-70-less/) has some information, and as always, refer to [the](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/fargate-capacity-providers.html) [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/ec2-and-fargate-spot.html).

If you cannot tolerate the service interruptions with the Spot market, your next best bet may be ECS with EC2 instances. Others may rightly suggest that ECS Fargate (without Spot) is easier since you wouldn't have to maintain EC2 instances, but it is also significantly more expensive. I'd choose ECS with EC2 instances and purchase a [Compute Savings Plan](https://aws.amazon.com/savingsplans/compute-pricing/) to bring down the cost.